# Unclosed questions: how do we compare to other SE sites, and can we do better?

Tags: discussion

We have a lot of old questions that reappear because they were never closed.

Sometimes the question was never answered, other times the question was answered but perhaps not to the OP's satisfaction, and still other times the question was abandoned despite a seemingly adequate answer.

How does our close rate compare to other SE sites, and is there something we can do to improve matters?

Comment: I have seen that there are some questions which either has already been answered on SO or their answer is present in the comments. How such questions can be closed, as one who has asked the question will never have any option for accepting answer. I admin that there can be few such questions but still number and count matters, if we want to improve our SQA Stack Exchange platform.